# Polymer iron-ajax call and how to modify/filter the response before binding happens?

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0, javascript-databinding

Polymer iron-ajax call and how to modify/filter the response before binding happens?

code wise is something like this:

```
    <iron-ajax url="{{seturl}}" last-response="{{carts}}" auto on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>

    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
       <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>
           <paper-header-panel>
              <cart-list carts="{{carts.values}}" selected-cart="{{selectedCart}}"></cart-list>
           </paper-header-panel>
       </paper-scroll-header-panel>
    </paper-drawer-panel>
```

So by the time I pass the {{carts.value}} to custom element `<cart-list>` I need it to filter a few items from the response, essentially the carts returns too much data, so I want to filter out a few of that data before I pass the carts binding to `<cart-list>`.

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is carts an array or an object? `carts.values` indicates an object, but filtering indicates an array. Regardless, there is some [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists) on filtering. You could set up an observer for carts that filters carts when carts has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the lastRespone part altogether, and have the on-response function do the filtering. So in the on respond function you remove all the junk and in the end say `this.carts = filteredObjectAsArray`

This would probably be beneficial in terms of performance as I assume `cart-list` has a `Dom-repeat`. If you pass the filtered array to it then it does not have to stamp all those items to the DOM, only the relevant ones.

Comment: You could also pass them all to the `dom-repeat` template and assign a filter there. I assume it doesn't stamp them out either if they don't match the filter. Filtering in the template might be better if the carts are also used somewhere else on the page so all the initial carts need to be maintained.

Comment: Yes, that's also true. I recall reading that filters do stamp the DOM and then hide the unnecessary stuff. Hiding/showing is then faster than destroying/recreating should the filter criteria change. So if that is a requirement it could be the better approach.